# Warframe not starting [wine]

Tags: wine, games

today I tried to install [Warframe](https://warframe.com) with wine. 
 I followed [this](https://forums.warframe.com/index.php?/topic/41660-guide-warframe-on-linux-with-wine) tutorial, but I always get a window which looks like this:

  [image]
 
When I press on "show details", it shows me [that](http://pastebin.com/SK25ZuaG).

I have installed an actual Arch Linux with wine-1.8-rc1.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to post a translation or somehow contrive for the message to be in English. This will broaden the group of people who might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Play on Linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/fr/app-2382-Warframe.html) to solve this.

If you installed PoL (Play on Linux), but it bugs, there is another dirty way: install Steam from PoL, then install Warframe on Steam on PoL, then run the Warframe.

A last thing, when I get this error, the launcher blocks my computer re-starting it self continuously. If this happened, two ways: shut down your internet connection to block the launcher progress and open a terminal OR open a new session by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and login. Run

```
killall Launcher.exe
```

(to kill all the launcher processes)
OR

```
top
```

it will open a full-screen programs manager. Look at the PID (under the column PID) of Launcher.exe, then

```
kill <pid>
```

Comment: thanks HalosGhost for this cleanup, this is my first answer and this is a reason of these mistakes. For the bad english spelling, it's because I'm not enlish, so it isn't perfect :)